# Swift's property oveservers don't get called in cascade

Tags: swift3, property-observer

Let's say I have a simple tree-like structure like this:

```
class Tree {
    weak var ancestor: Tree?
    var children = [Tree]()
}
```

Every node of the tree keeps a reference to its children, and a weak one (to avoid reference cycles) to the *oldest* ancestor.

I'd like to automatically update the ancestor property of the all nodes of a subtree whenever I set it on its root.

```
let grandParent = Tree()
let parent      = Tree()
let child       = Tree()
let grandChild  = Tree()

child.children.append(grandChild)
parent.children.append(child)
grandParent.children.append(parent)

// Should set ancestor in the whole hierarchy.
grandParent.ancestor = grandParent
```

I've tried to achieve that with property observers, iterating on the node's children whenever its ancestor is set so that the value is propagated, but noticed neither `didSet` nor `willSet` gets called passed the first child.
Here's the code I've been experiencing with:

```
weak var ancestor: Tree? = nil {
    didSet {
        for child in self.children {
            child.ancestor = self.ancestor
        }
    }
}
```

As expected, the ancestor of `grandParent` is properly set, and so is that of the `parent`. 
However, those of its descendants (`child` and `grandChild`) are not.
Note that I've been observing the same result with `willSet` (of course adjusting the above code to take into account that `self.ancestor` wouldn't have changed yet).

Could someone point to me what I'm missing here?

---

I could do what I want with computed properties, with a very similar approach.
But I find it less elegant than the one with property observers and would rather avoid it if possible.
Nevertheless, this snippet gets things done.

```
var ancestor: Tree? {
    get {
        return self._ancestor
    }

    set(newAncestor) {
        self._ancestor = newAncestor
        for child in self.children {
            child.ancestor = newAncestor
        }
    }
}

private weak var _ancestor: Tree? = nil
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've seen this mentioned before, and it seems to be a Swift bug that is triggered if you try to set a property inside a willSet / didSet on another instance of the same type.

Oddly enough, syntax matters and seems to work around the bug.  For example, I can make your code work by changing your `didSet` to this:

```
weak var ancestor: Tree? = nil {
    didSet {
        children.forEach { $0.ancestor = ancestor }
    }
}
```

It's doing essentially the same thing, but doesn't trigger the compiler bug.

---

### UPDATE

This has previously been filed as a bug on swift.org and is still open:  https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-419

And there are a couple additional comments clarifying the cause and what workarounds can avoid it here:
https://twitter.com/uint_min/status/804795245728698368

Comment: Just a small remark for those who would copy/paste your code. You should replace `$0` by `$0.ancestor`.